# Do I need a ViewController container or a composite view?

Tags: ios

I need to implement an accordion control for iOS.  By accordion, I mean a UI like this:

[image]

I see two basic ways to do this, but I'm not sure which one to choose.

Method #1: Create a ViewController container, something like a `UITabBarController`, except that instead of showing tabs at the bottom, I draw a vertical stack of buttons, and when you tap one, the corresponding panel opens and shows the corresponding view controller's view.

Method #2: Create a composite view, add a bunch of views directly to it, and show/hide them as needed.

How do I choose here?  What would make me want to treat the sub-units as view controllers vs views?

Comment: What about method #3: Table view using custom cells? I am a huge fan of table views, so I tend to see table structures everywhere :-)

Comment: @herzbube: I know that people use table views like that, but it seems like an odd tool for the job, since the data rows aren't the same kind of thing, and you have to do all kinds of complicated stuff to deal with uneven row heights, and different kinds of views for different indexes.

Comment: iOS has a pretty rich set of open source controls for this type of thing.  Here's one and I'm sure there are quite a few more via Google: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uiexpandabletableview

Comment: I believe you'll want at least to use `UIControl` instead of `UIView` as a top level type, but I also believe you'll end up with recreating `UITableView` (and probably `UITableViewController` as well).

Comment: @A-Live: About UIControl instead of UIVIew, what's the reason for that?

Comment: @Joshua Frank For actions binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if I can avoid it I try not to subclass `UIView` and instead do everything within `UIViewController` subclasses. A controller is usually required anyway (model/view glue code, user interaction, delegate stuff, notification handling, etc.), so if no custom drawing is needed it is usually possible to do without a `UIView` subclass.

In your case I could envision one reusable `UIViewController` subclass that represents a list entry. It has the following responsibilities:

- Create two alternate view hierarchies (collapsed/button, expanded/panel)
- Toggle between the view hierarchies in reaction to user interaction (with/without animation)

And another `UIViewController` subclass that represents the entire list. It has the following responsibilities:

- Override the appropriate methods from `UIViewController` to make it into a container VC
- Add/remove child VCs as appropriate to the internal model
- Possibly adjust the container view in reaction to collapse/expand events in its child VCs